# Python unittest report passed test

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Hello I have a test module like the following under "test.py":

```
class TestBasic(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # set up in here

class TestA(TestBasic):
    def test_one(self):
        self.assertEqual(1,1)

    def test_two(self):
        self.assertEqual(2,1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

And this works pretty good, but I need a way to print which test passed, for example I could print the output to the console:

```
test_one: PASSED
test_two: FAILED
```

Now the twist, I could add a print statement right after the self.assertEqual() and that would be a passed test and I could just print it, but I need to run the test from a different module, let's say "test_reporter.py" where I have something like this:

```
import test
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(test)
results = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=0).run(suite)
```

at this point with results is when I build a report.

So please any suggestion is welcome

Thanks !!

Comment: change verbosity to 2, and you will see output from each case

Comment: why don't you post it as an answer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like [Corey's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679660/python-unittest-report-passed-test#comment24002393_16679660) mentioned, if you set `verbosity=2` unittest will print the result of each test run.

```
results = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

---

If you want a little more flexibility - and you might since you are creating suites and using test runners - I recommend that you take a look at [Twisted Trial](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedTrial). It extends Python's `unittest` module and provides a few more assertions and reporting features.

Writing your tests will be exactly the same (besides subclassing  twisted.trial.unittest.TestCase vs python's unittest) so your workflow won't change. You can still use your `TestLoader` but you'll have the options of many more TestReporters http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.1.0/api/twisted.trial.reporter.html.

For example, the default TestReporter is `TreeReporter` which returns the following output:
[image]

Comment: Hello I tried you solution and works pretty good, the problem is that passed test are not showing with the [OK] and failed test do show with [FAIL] any idea ?

Comment: If you want the output to look like the screenshot, you need to install [Twisted Trial](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedTrial) and then run it using `trial test_file.py` instead of `python -m unittest`

Comment: Yes i did that I was missint to subclass from twisted.trial.unittest.TestCase, it works now, thanks